# How to empty keyboard buffer in a DOS batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file, buffer, dos

I've made a simple batch script to  generate CodeIgniter folder structure (scaffolding) but... the script remembers the last value of the %1 enviroment variable because there is a keyboard buffer. Any simple solution? I'm using Windows 7

```
@echo off
REM by Pablo Bozzolo (2011)

REM HOW to empty keyboard buffer before ???
if "%1"=="" goto inicio
set (%uname%)=(%1)
goto creacion

:inicio
set /P uname=Nombre del modulo ? 
if "%uname%"=="" goto inicio

echo Desea crear el modulo %uname%
choice 
if errorlevel 2 goto end

:creacion
mkdir %uname%
cd %uname%
mkdir config
mkdir controller
mkdir libraries
mkdir models
mkdir views

type NUL > ./controller/%uname%.php
type NUL > ./models/%uname%_m.php
cd..
echo Modulo %uname% creado!
goto end
:end
```

Comment: How did you come to this conclusion? %1 is the first command-line argument to the script. It has nothing to do with the keyboard buffer.

Comment: I also think he misunderstands the use of %1, but looking at what the script does. I guess he want to be able to do something if %1 is not passed to the script.

Comment: Hi!!! my idea is this script can be used from command line and also as Windows program ... that's way.... I use %1 too                                         - J. Kommer: thanks for editing :))

Comment: I suppose you have more basic problems, than to empty a keyboard buffer... `set (%uname%)=(%1)` can't ever work, it will create probably a variable named `()` with the content of `%1` surrounded by brackets - if `%1` is `hello` then you got `()=(hello)`

Comment: can it be that the real question is to empty the keyboard buffer before the SET /P ? please don't, this would break a consolidated user expectation in windows environments.

Comment: i've found a few elegant solutions for [if "%1"==""](http://groups.google.com/group/alt.msdos.batch.nt/browse_thread/thread/27bd45d7b06f7bd6)

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to handle %1 if its empty, simply write

```
if "%~1" LEQ "" set uname=%1
```

Comment: The empty test of user980631 seems to work, but `set (%uname%)=(%1)` is syntax garbage

Comment: True. Just following his code. 
That's not the only concern though:
    `type NUL > ./controller/%uname%.php` will cause problems too. Or not specifically problems, but it's syntax garbage as you say :)